# How to create 2k sized vector in k sized loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to solve a system of simple differential equations. At some point I need to solve non-linear system of algebraic equations with Newton method. I would like to efficiently create a right hand side vector using Table[] or similar command. The problem is that the system consists of two equations, so what I need is:

```
F=Table[
(*do something*)
,{i,1,k}]
```

but in fact $F$ should have $2k$ entries. For example for $k=5$ `Length[F]` should return $10$. How to achieve that efficiently? 
I know I can create different values for odd indexes and even, but then I need additional `If[]` or to break the whole code into two `Table[]` executions what I would like to avoid. I could possibly also create two element lists {a,b}, and flatten it at the end...
But It still seems quite expensive.

Comment: On what basis do you assert that `Flatten` is expensive? Did you time it?

Comment: If you are looking for alternatives to Flatten you could try Last@Reap[ Do[ Sow[ .. ] , {i,k},{j,2} ] ]. Doubt its faster than Flatten@Table[ ..] though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this because I was a but surprised by the result..

```
n = 10^6
Last@Last@Reap[Do[ Sow[2 i + j - 2], {i, n}, {j, 2}]] == Range[2 n] // Timing
-> {3.307221, True}
Table[Unevaluated@Sequence[2 i + 1 - 2, 2 i + 2 - 2], {i, n}] == Range[2 n] // Timing
-> {1.918812, True}
Flatten@Table[ 2 i + j - 2, {i, n}, {j, 2}] == Range[2 n] // Timing
-> {0.093601, True}
Riffle[Table[ 2 i + 1 - 2, {i, n}], Table[ 2 i + 2 - 2, {i, n}]] == Range[2 n] // Timing
-> {0.078001, True}
```

Note the Riffle approach might really win out depending on how your expression simplifies.

Comment: One more example: `Table[Unevaluated@Sequence[2 i - 1, 2 i], {i, n}] == Range[2 n] // Timing`. It is quite slow, but a bit faster then `Reap`/`Sow`.

Comment: nice, added that to the answer for reference..

Comment: How about `Flatten@Table[{2i-1,2i},{i,n}]`?